# Find $\sup(E)$ for $E := \{n,m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \}$

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

We propose $1$ as the LUB of $E$. Proof:

**First step: 1 is an upper bound of $E$**:

Suppose $\exists x \in E, x > 1 $ Then:
$$\exists n,m \in \mathbb{N},\frac{1}{n} - \frac 1 m > 1 $$
$$\Rightarrow  m - n > mn $$
$$\Rightarrow mn - m +n < 0 $$

But, by the properties of $\mathbb{N}, mn > m > 0$ and so $mn - m + n>0$
There is a contradiction, and we conclude that $1$ is an upper bound of $E$.

**Second step: $1$ is the least upper bound of $E$**:

Let us assume $\exists \epsilon >0$, such that $1 - \epsilon$ be an upper bound of $E$. Then:
$$\forall x \in E\, x \le 1-\epsilon$$

However we can find $x \in E $ s.t. $x > 1- \epsilon$
Without losing generality, we can choose n = 1, in which case, we must find $m \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying:
$$-\frac{1}{m} > -\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow m\epsilon > 1$$

By the archimedian property of the real numbers, m exists. Therefore $1 - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for a given $\epsilon > 0$. Therefore 1 is the least upper bound of $E$.

Therefore $\sup(E) = 1$.

I'd like to know if there any 'kinks' in this proof. Would there be a way to solve without necessarily letting $n = 1$? It feels to me like an 'unclean' step. (I am fairly new to rigorous proofs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good but the first part is a bit too long. Note that if $x \in E$ then $$x = \frac 1n - \frac 1m < \frac 1n \le 1$$ so that $1$ is an upper bound.

Comment: Maybe a step should be taken to show that $\frac{1}{n} \le 1$? Something along the lines of $\frac{1}{n+1} \le \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{1} \le 1$

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, but for section $1$ I would not use contradiction. We can do the following to prove $1$ is an upper bound:

Take $e\in E$, then $e=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb N$. We have:

$e=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\leq 1-\frac{1}{m}\leq 1$, since $e\leq 1$ for all $e\in E$ we have that $1$ is an upper bound for $E$.